# Why array.length is not working while array is filled by a async function in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, async-await, es6-promise, web-audio-api

I'm learing WebAudio API. I'm facing a problem with it. Basically things are asynchronous here...so im getting a bit confused. Please help.Here is my code:-

```
//"use strict";

var sources = new Array();
var actx;
var songs = ['src1.mp3', 'src2.mp3'];

async function start() {
  console.log("WELCOME!!");
  try {
    actx = new AudioContext();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('WebAudio api is not supported!!');

  }
  await getBuffers(actx, songs);
  console.log(sources);
  console.log(sources.length);
}

function load_song(url) {
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    request.onload = () => {
      let audioData = request.response;
      resolve(audioData);
    }
    request.onerror = () => {
      reject(new error("Could not load the song:- " + url));
    }

    request.send();
  });
  return promise;
}
//creats buffers
async function getBuffers(actx, songs) {
  // let buffer_list = new Array();

  for (let x = 0; x < songs.length; x++) {
    let temp = actx.createBufferSource();
    await load_song(songs[x]).then((audioData) => {
      actx.decodeAudioData(audioData).then((decodedAudioData) => {
        temp.buffer = decodedAudioData;
        sources.push(temp);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
    });
  }
  //console.log(buffers.length);
}
async function play() {
  //start();
  sources[0].start(0);
  //sources[1].start(0);
}

function stop() {
  sources[0].stop(0);
  //sources[1].stop(0);
}
```

Here in the two lines `console.log(sources)` and `console.log(sources.length)`. Here the results are. Why `console.log(sources.length)` is 0?
Please help me........Thank you.

[image: in web colsole here is the result.]

Comment: `console.log(sources)` is evaluated when you expand it in the developer console due to chrome's behavior, and by that point the array is filled, however when you log the length, the array is not filled yet.

Comment: `await load_song(songs[x]).then` your mixing `async/await` with a thenable callback..   try `const audioData = await load_song(songs[x])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return

```
actx.decodeAudioData(audioData).then((decodedAudioData) => {
```

As you are not returning it, you dont `await` it. Therefore the log appears before the array gets filled, however `console.log(sources)` is live, so you see the latest change.

Such mistakes are more unlikely to happen when you use `await` everywhere, and thats also easier to read IMO:

```
async function getBuffers(actx, songs) {
  const sources = [];  //mutating a global variable isnt good, so lets make it local
  for (const song of songs) { //for...of is so beautiful, why dont you use it?
   try { //this is similar to .catch
    let temp = actx.createBufferSource();
    const audioData = await load_song(song);

    const decodedAudioData =  await actx.decodeAudioData(audioData);
    temp.buffer = decodedAudioData;
    sources.push(temp);
   } catch(e){ console.error(e); } //okay that does not count as an error handler...
  }
  return sources; //getBuffers implies that it returns sth
}
```

Comment: `use await everywhere`  I was just about to post an answer with this in mind.. :)..  Also I would even say take out the `try / catch` as this really should be allowed to propagate, and some higher level error handling look after any reporting.  oh, just noticed you put a comment at the end of the `catch`.

Comment: @keith agree. But i want to stay as close to the OPs code as possible. I already changed alot i dont want to overwhelm him.

Comment: @Jonas W. Isn't <b>actx.decodeAudioData()</b> takes three arguments? and <b>sources[] </b> i've taken it global for debugging purpose...

Comment: Btw @Jonas W. What is IMO??

Comment: @Jonas W. Can you be more descriptive about your code..a promise is returned from load_song()...you are again passing that promise to decodeAudioData()...I don't understand it...can you please give the working principle...how is it working?

Comment: @uzumaki 1) i dont know, thats taken from your code. 2) okay thats possible. Should he changed in production 3) in my opinion 4) no im not, please have a look at the `await` docs....

Comment: @Jonas I got it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should change your `getBuffers` code for something like this

```
async function getBuffers(actx, songs) {
    try {
        for (let song of songs) {
            let temp = actx.createBufferSource();
            var audioData = await load_song(songs[x])
            var decodedAudioData = await actx.decodeAudioData(audioData)
            temp.buffer = decodedAudioData;
            sources.push(temp);
        }
    } catch (e) { console.log(e) }
}
```